# как убрать путь в nginx и сделать redirect?

Tags: nginx, seo, redirect

Есть запрсы условно https://example.com/ru/paths или https://example.com/en/paths, после ru и en может буть любой путь и с параметрами и без. Вопрос как убрать ru и en и оставить например https://example.com/paths. На новом сайте нет указаанию языка в пути, но гугл сканирует их а это плохо для seo

Comment: Из вопроса не очень понятно что вам надо. Вы говорите что вам надо убрать `ru` и `en` из пути, но при этом в следующем же предложении вы говорите что на новом сайте у вас этих языков в пути и так нет. Вы путаете людей...если нужно только редирект сделать, то так и напишите

Comment: в nginx сделать редирект с  https://example.com/RU/paths на https://example.com/paths убрав отуда RU это нужно для роботов гугла они до сих пор стучатся на старый адрес (типа  https://example.com/RU/paths ) они где-то у себя сохранили. но их нет сейсас по такому пути и  получают 404

Comment: это все в вопросе лучше сразу писать

Comment: получилось что или у вас остались вопросы?

Answer (score 0):

все просто

нужно составить директиву `rewrite` с помощью регулярного выражения, которое будет обрабатываеть все запросы начинающиеся с en или с ru

выглядеть оно будет примерно так:

```
^/(en|ru)(.*)$
```

- `^` - символ начала строки
- `$` - символ конца строки
- `(...)` - группировка, позже к ней можно будет обращаться через знак доллара и номера этой группировки символов (`$1`,`$2`)
- `.` - может обозначать любой символ
- `.*` - любое количество любых символов

как итог - `^/(en|ru)(.*)$` соответствует любой строке, начинающейся с `/en` или с `/ru` и с любым набором символов до конца строки после. Причем мы сгруппировали код языка и оставшуюся адресную строку, чтобы впоследствии с ними можно было работать.

В конфигурацию нужно будет добавить строку

```
rewrite ^/(en|ru)(.*)$ $2 permanent;
```

здесь мы объявляем директиву rewrite и передаем ей шаблон поиска в виде, составленного выше регулярного выражения и строкой замены (`$2`).

В данном случае мы будем заменять на вторую группу - то есть на оставшуюся строку.

Добавляется все это в блоке server

```
server {
    # ...
    rewrite ^/(en|ru)(.*)$ $2 permanent;
    # ...
}
```

на живом примере:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

все работает как надо